# Why do we make pointer objects?

Tags: c++

I come from a more of the Java background, however I have come across things like this:

```
SDL_Surface *dot = NULL;
```

Why is it we put the asterisk in front of the object?

Why can't this be done:

```
SDL_Surface dot = NULL;
```

What is the difference between the two?

I know it's a pointer, but what happens exactly?

Comment: Pointers are not a simple topic which can be explained in a SO answer.  I'd strongly advise you to get a good book about C++.

Comment: I don't know what SDL_Surface is - a struct, a class?  Pointer allows for dynamic object creation on the heap.  The asterisk denotes a pointer to an object.  I would advise you to go read some c/c++ fundamentals books.  If you have to start dealing with lots of code with pointer, and you have a Java background, you will be in trouble otherwise.

Comment: People need to stop down-voting just because of the complexity of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it [that] we put the asterisk in front of the object?

We use the asterisk `*` as part of the type to declare a pointer. Without it, the compiler wouldn't know that it's a pointer, it will just interpret it as a regular object.

```
int x;  // an integer
int *x; // a pointer to an integer
```

Java has `null` but `NULL` in C++ is a preprocessor macro that expands to `0`. When pointers are set to `0` it typically means that they haven't been initialized with a value.

```
int *x = NULL; // same as int *x = 0
```

> What is the difference between the two?

I think [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson6.html) answers that question.

Comment: So what happens when I do cout << dot; ?

Comment: @TeraByte You'll get a compiler error because `*` is not a pointer, it's an operator that when used in certain contexts can have different connotations. It's not a universal symbol for a pointer. How about doing `int y, *x = &y; cout << x;`. That will print the address of `y`.

Comment: so when I do SDL_Surface *dot = NULL, I'm creating a pointer to an empty address?

Comment: @TeraByte Well, the address is not empty per se, you're actually making the pointer point to address `0`. Note that dereferencing a pointer set to 0 (otherwise known as a null pointer) yeilds [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior‎)

Comment: Ok, so, *dot means I'm dereferencing it, so it will be undefined, if I just use dot it is 0, and if I use &dot, I get the address of the actual pointer? I think...

Comment: This is how you dereference a pointer: `int *x = &y; *x = 5;`. There I dereferenced `x` and assigned the value at that address to 5. If a pointer hasn't been given a value or is pointing to `NULL` (or 0) and you dereference that pointer, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @TeraByte Just to clarify, what do you mean by `dot`? Is `dot` the asterik symbol `*` or is it a variable (like a pointer)?

Comment: no, I'm actually following a SDL tutorial, http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson16/index.php dot is a SDL_Surface object

Comment: @TeraByte Can you accept my answer please? And is there anything else you're having trouble with pertaining to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a pointer is a reference to a adress. If you have something like:

```
int temp = 1;
int *p; // or int* p or int * p
p = &temp;
```

You are not assigning the value of temp to p, but you're making a reference to an address in the stack. The difference is clear: it's *where*, not *how much*.

Reversely, you can do this:

```
int temp2 = 0;
temp2 = *p; //temp2 is now 1
```

For further reading on that topic, refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Comment: `a pointer is a reference to a address`. Uhm, no it's not, a pointer is a pointer.

Comment: Maybe it's my english, but a pointer points to an address. And how is circular logic helping when explaining something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SDL_Surface` is a class...

`SDL_Surface *dot = NULL;`

This means `dot` is a pointer to objects of `SDL_Surface` and it is initialized to NULL. Means it is not pointing to any object. Pointers are variables which holds the address of another variable. In order to make `dot` point to a `SDL_Surface` object, you have to allocate the object and assign the address to `dot`. In C++ you can do this with `new` operator.

`SDL_Surface *dot = new SDL_Surface`

This will create the object in heap. So you have to manually deallocate it using `delete` operateor

`delete dot`